# Execute an SQL stored procedure with an Azure Webjob

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-webjobs

I followed the steps on [this page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/) to create a webjob that is scheduled to run every five minutes. The purpose of the webjob is to execute an SQL stored procedure. The problem is that I can't find any script to make the webjob execute the stored procedure.

On the other hand, with the Scheduler of Azure mobile aps, the [following script](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ms-tech_learning_with_prasant/archive/2014/07/09/scheduling-job-on-sql-azure.aspx) will execute the stored procedure:

```
function Execute_updateNames() {
     mssql.query('Exec dbo.updateNames',{
     success: function(results){
     console.log("Successful...");
     },
      error: function(err) {
        console.log("Error is: " + err);
     }
 });
```

}

My question is how can I execute a stored procedure with an Azure Webjob. A script sample is well appreciated.

Comment: have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32217907/how-to-run-node-js-in-azure-webjobs

Comment: It refers to the same page I've followed. I know the steps to run the script but my problem is that I don't know how to execute the stored procedure.

Comment: You need to look at the Execute method: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#execute

Comment: If you figured this out please share. Can’t find documentation for this anywhere.